# Filtro en consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

> Colaborador ( id)
>
> Historia (id,idcolaborador,fchIngreso,fchEgreso)
>
> Evaluacion (id, id colaborador, periodo)
>
> Periodo (id, idEvaluacion,FchaPeriodo)

Lo que tengo que lograr es sacar a los colaboradores que la fecha de egreso sea menor a la fecha del periodo de la evaluación.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado para lograr eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar considero que deberías tener un poco mas de orden en tus tablas, especialmente en los identificadores.

Tus tablas deben ser algo asi

> Tabla colaborador

```
   Create table Colaborador (
     idColaborador int,
     nombreColaborador varchar(20)
    )
```

> TABLA historia

```
create table Historia (
 idHistoria int,
 idColaborador int,
 fchIngreso DATE,
 fchEgreso DATE
)
```

> Tabla Evalucacion

```
create table Evaluacion (
 idEvalucion int,
 idColaborador int,
 IdPeriodo int
)
```

> Tabla Periodo

```
create table Periodo (
 idPeriodo int,
 idEvaluacion int,
 FechaPeriodo DATE
)
```

posterior a eso creas tu relación lo puedes hacer gráficamente, lo omito para no alargar el código y la idea es relacionarte para que mantengas orden

---

si lo que requieres realizar es una consulta entre varias tablas, lo que puedes realizar es emplear la funcion `inner join` de sql

Respondiendo a tu consulta lo que puedes hacer es algo como esto

```
select *, historia.FechaEgreso from  colaborador
inner join historia on historia.idColaborador = colaborador.idColaborador
inner join evaluacion on evaluacion.idColaborador = colaborador.idColaborador
inner join periodo on periodo.idPerido = Evaluacion.idPeriodo
where historia.FechaEgreso < periodo.FechaPeriodo
```

Espero poder orientarte

Comment: Gracias por toda la información, de hecho las tablas son mucho mas grandes y ya están creadas. Pero puntualmente esa era la información importante del caso.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías relacionar con `inner join` todas las tablas involucradas en la consulta para luego poder realizar el filtro. quedaria algo así:

```
Select C.* From Colaborador C
Inner Join Historia H on C.id = H.idcolaborador
Inner Join Evaluacion E on C.id = E.idcolaborador
Inner Join Periodo P on E.id = P.idEvaluacion
Where H.fchEgreso < P.FchaPeriodo
```

En el `Select` trae los datos de la tabla Colaborador. si necesitas otros datos es cuestión de agregarlos después del `Select` y listo.

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT c.id 
FROM colaborador c, historia h, evaluacion e, periodo p
WHERE c.id = h.id_colaborador AND c.id = e.id_colaborador AND e.id = 
      p.id_evaluacion     AND h.fec_egreso < p.fec_periodo;
```

Creo que esta solución podría funcionar independientemente del SGBD utilizado.

Comment: por favor lee [answer], se te agradece el apoyo pero responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad; edita por favor y explica como esto soluciona el problema del OP